# How to add the column by default in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables called `login` and `Roles`.

In the `login` table, I have these fields:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[login]
   ([Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Uname] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Pwd] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT [PK_login_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Uname] ASC)
```

In the `roles` table I have these fields:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles]
   ([Uname] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Valid] [int] NOT NULL
 )
```

Now what I need is if I fill the `uname` as some xyz I would like to fill the same `uname` in the role table automatically in the corresponding field that i makes as foreign key...

Comment: what's the point of the id identity column in login if you make uname your primary key? Have you thought about why you need a separate roles table?  why can valid not be a row in the login table? is there only a one to one mapping here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using a Trigger.  You may or may not want to execute this code on an  `Insert` and / or `Update`  Further details on triggers can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsertUserIntoRoles ON Login

FOR Insert

AS    

INSERT INTO Roles (UName, Valid)
SELECT Uname, 1    
FROM Inserted
```

Although I think it would be better if you just added the code to insert the username into the `Roles` table within the Stored Procedure to create the user.

Also, you are aware that you are creating all this on the `master` database?

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to put a trigger on inserts to the original table.

This [microsoft article on triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx) will tell you how they work.

Comment: your answer is technically correct, but conflicts with my religious views on creating a relational database.

Comment: @Nick Kavadias: you shouldn't have any religious views when it comes to databases... just opinions based on facts. How would you solve this issue then??

Comment: @marc_s in my perfect world I wouldn't de-normalize data that way unless there was a very good reason. Like i said, using a trigger is the technical way to do this, but why do it in the first place?

Comment: @Nick Kavadias: I don't see this as denormalization - it would appear the link between Roles and Users is done via the `UName` property. Whether that's a good idea (it being a large string) is another story - but if you want to link the two tables on this column, you do need this in both places, no??